# not a mach-o file error in Python - mismatching architecture

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries, apple-m1, rosetta

For a project, I'm reading a `.so` file with the `ctypes.CDLL` and `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(...)`, this is done in a devcontainer. The docker image is based off the following:

> `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:3.10`.

Notice the `linux/amd64` platform. When checking system information with `uname`, it shows the x86_64 architecture: `Linux ceb596f614b7 5.10.124-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 30 08:18:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. This runs fine, and loads the library without any errors.

However, I have a M1 Mac, where I installed Rosett and Python on that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71873666/2989034). When I check the system information then, I get the following, also a x86_64 architecture.

> `Darwin MacBook-van-Bas.local 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Aug 22 20:19:52 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 x86_64`

When I load the file in a Rosetta terminal, I get the following error:

> OSError: dlopen(/Users/bas/lib.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Users/bas/lib.so'
> (not a mach-o file)

How is this even possible? It's the same x86_64 architecture. Is my only option working in a devcontainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the source code and re-building to a Mach-o file. But to answer my question: [Apple platforms draw an important distinction between architecture and platform](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/717724?answerId=732915022#732915022).