# Build PySide2 for Apple Silicon architecture

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I’m trying to build my project dependencies for a native Apple Silicon support. However, I’m having issues to compile PySide2. I know… I know… it’s too old and it’s better to use PySide6. We want to upgrade that too. But my point is to know if I can do the arm64 support first.

To build PySide2 I’m using:

- macOS 12.6
- XCode 14
- I compiled Python 3.9 with no issues.
- QT 5.15.10
- libclang 12
- pyside-setup (source code) 5.15.2.1

My error message when I try to build PySide2 with `python setup.py install  --qmake=...` is: `Something's broken.  UCHAR_MAX should be defined in limits.h.`

I realized that since QT 5.15.4 I can use the option `QMAKE_APPLE_DEVICE_ARCHS="x86_64 arm64"` but I’m not sure how to pass it to pyside-setup.

I have a couple questions:

1. Is it possible to compile PySide2 (QT5) for arm?
2. How can I build PySide2 locally without a Qt license just for development purposes? I have my file only on CI and when I try locally I get:

   Error: Qt license file was not found!
   Project ERROR: License check failed! Giving up ...
   error: Failed to query for Qt's QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.

Answer (score 0):

[Qt_for_Python Wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python) shows that MacOS for Apple chips supports source code building can be built from version 6.2.2.

In this [link](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_38410494/article/details/114994524), the blogger successfully compiled PySide2(some components) but still eventually some components(`QtWebEngineWidgets`) were missing.

> maybe web related components in Qt rely on the underlying x86 platform,so Qt5 for arm not support)

Answer (score 0):

While I know the question is for the apple silicon architecture, there is an alternate way to do this by the x86 version of python using Rosetta

1. Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75827006/5282368) to install the x86 version of python
2. Install PySide2

   ```
   pip install PySide2
   ```